# issue in StoryBoard: Other views at the top of the table view are not visable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, custom-cell

I have started an app using **story board**.

In that i have used tabbar controller

In a **view,** I have Table view in that having a custom cell, And I have added **a search bar at the top of the Table view**. as shown bellow

[image]

The problem is **when** I add **Search bar very close to the navigation bar, It does not display** and if i added **little down it was displayed**

[image]

[image]

what was the issue is in 2px difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to IB Inspector

Select search bar and set AutoSizing Mask like this attached Picture.. Enable left, right, top and center position.

[image]